# Python Tkinter TreeviewSelect event got called twice (it should only be called once)

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am having a problem with the Tkinter Treeview code below. The code generates a Combobox and a treeview.

Every time, when I select a value in Combobox, it will automatically update the value in the treeview, like following:

[image]

And the last value in the treeview will be automatically selected:

[image]

When one row of treeview is selected, it will trigger a event `<<TreeviewSelect>>` in function `__getUpdateTypeSelected`. I only expect `__getUpdateTypeSelected` be called once everytime I select a new Combobox value. However, it is called twice if there is already values in treeview.

Here is the output everytime I select a new item in Combobox

```
Update Group
Update Type
Update Group
Update Type
Update Type
Update Group
Update Type
Update Type
```

The reason that it is called twice is from the treeview `delete` function, it seems that the `delete` function will cause the tree `selection`. I already tried to disable it by using a `self.selection_event_enabled = False`, however, the `__getUpdateTypeSelected` function is still called twice. May I ask if you have some suggestions? Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# ===
# APP
# ===
class App(tk.Tk):
    # -------
    # Initial
    # -------
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.accounts_dict = {}
        self.accounts_dict['A'] = {"Aa": {1, 2, 3}, "Ab": {2, 3, 4}}
        self.accounts_dict['B'] = {"Ba": {3, 4, 5}, "Bb": {4, 5, 6}}
        self.accounts_dict['C'] = {"Ca": {5, 6, 7}, "Cb": {6, 7, 8}}

        self.selection_event_enabled = True  # Flag to control selection event

        self.__create_group()
        self.__create_tree_type()

    # -----------------
    # Create tree group
    # -----------------
    def __create_group(self):
        self.groupCombo = ttk.Combobox(self, values=list(self.accounts_dict.keys()), state="readonly")
        self.groupCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.__getUpdateGroup)
        self.groupCombo.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.E)

    # ----------------
    # Create tree type
    # ----------------
    def __create_tree_type(self):
        self.tree_type = ttk.Treeview(self, height=6, selectmode='browse')
        self.tree_type.heading('#0', text='Type', anchor='w')
        self.tree_type.column('#0', anchor='w', width=200, minwidth=100)
        self.tree_type.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        # Bind item selection
        self.tree_type.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', self.__getUpdateTypeSelected)

    def __getUpdateGroup(self, event):
        print("Update Group")

        # Temporarily disable the selection event
        self.selection_event_enabled = False

        # Remove previous items in tree_type
        for item in self.tree_type.get_children():
            self.tree_type.delete(item)

        # Get insert new items to tree_type
        onegroup = self.groupCombo.get()
        for onetype in self.accounts_dict[onegroup].keys():
            self.tree_type.insert('', tk.END, text=onetype)

        children = self.tree_type.get_children()
        if children:
            self.tree_type.selection_set(children[-1])

        # Re-enable the selection event
        self.selection_event_enabled = True

    # --------------------------------
    # Event when tree_type is selected
    # --------------------------------
    def __getUpdateTypeSelected(self, event):

        # Process the selection event only if enabled
        if self.selection_event_enabled:
            print("Update Type")
            # Your code here
            pass

# ====
# Main
# ====
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Update:

I found that if I add `self.update()` after `treeview delete function`, it is only called once.

```
        # Remove previous items in tree_type
        for item in self.tree_type.get_children():
            self.tree_type.delete(item)
        self.update()
```

Comment: Note that when you delete the existing items in the treeview, the event is triggered.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for your reply. I tried to use `selection_event_enabled = False`, to disable the event. However, I do not understand why  `print("Update Type")` is still called in `__getUpdateTypeSelected`.

Comment: maybe `self.tree_type.selection_set()` or `elf.tree_type.insert()` also triggers `event`. I tried `update()` after loop with `insert()` and it seems it gives one `"Update Type"`

Comment: Yea, `self.update()` will fix the problem.

Comment: @furas `.insert()` does not trigger the event because no selection change happens.

Comment: @acw1668 I was only guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

We need to call `self.update()` immediately after `treeview delete`. This `update` will call `__getUpdateTypeSelected` when `self.selection_event_enabled` is not enabled, so `Update Type` will not be called this time.

```
        # Remove previous items in tree_type
        for item in self.tree_type.get_children():
            self.tree_type.delete(item)
        self.update()
```

If `self.update()` is not called, the selection event will be triggered later when `self.selection_event_enabled` is set to `True`, then `Update Type` will be called twice.